# How do I access post body in WSO2 prototype rest API javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, wso2

in WSO2 api gateway I want to prototype a few POST requests using inline javascript. I am trying to figure out how to get the post body value which is going to be json. Its a pretty old version of WSO2 (I think v5.0).

```
//URL: /a/b/{u1}/c?p1=123
mc.setProperty('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
var u1 = mc.getProperty('uri.var.u1'); 
var p1 = mc.getProperty('query.param.p1');
var postBody = mc.getProperty(???????????);
mc.setPayloadJSON('{ "data" : "' + p1 + '|||' + p2+ '"}');
```

This script is correctly printing the values if they are in the query string or the URI but cant seem to figure out how to get the POST body.

Comment: Consider using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/): https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html

Comment: What does this have to do with my question.

Comment: It has *everything* to do with your question.  If you're not already familiar with them, Postman, Fiddler and Chrome Developer Tools are *very* useful tools to learn. If you want to "prototype a few POST requests" - perhaps by interacting with a "live" WSO2 REST service - then Postman can be a *very* fast and effective way to do it.  You don't necessarily *need* to write JS code or fiddle with transform.js to analyze the underlying JSON messages back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if `mc.setPayloadJSON(...)` works, its should also work:

`var body = mc.getPayloadJSON();`

Comment: It returns an empty object { }

Comment: OK, you can try `mc.getPayloadXML();` But it's showing the XML representation of JSON.. not exacly what you expect. Is wierd, because I checked this in APIM 3.2 the getPayloadJSON is listed in documenttion, but doesnt show the JSON.. maybe it is a bug?

Comment: those are both empty. I give up on prototyping

Answer (score 0):

I simply found its easier to write a spring boot app and have that return data rather than mess with WSO2 horribly documented prototypes. I spent a day trying to figure out WSO2 prototyping vs 1 hour to make a real springboot app. My advice: DONT USE WSO2 PROTOTYPING UNLESS YOU ARE RETURNING THE MOST BASIC RESPONSES.